# Python Pandas combine

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the Python pandas dataframe below, I want to combine the amount paid column based on employee ID.

[dataframe]

[image: 1]

Comment: Do you need [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691) ?

Answer (score -1):

Well try:

```
dataframe.groupby('EMPLOYEE_ID')['AMOUNT_PAID'].sum()
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.